# How to move generated query type classes before compiling in Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I've managed to generate query type classes (.java) using Gradle, however they're being moved to build/classes/main along with compiled classes by default. How would I move them to src/main/java so I can reference them at compile time?

Here's my Gradle build script:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.3'
    compile 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.1.3'
    compile 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.3:jpa'


    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

**Edit**

As per my comment - I'm trying to move generated classes to directory src/generated/java and then add that location to the source directories so they can get compiled. I've tried the following, but it doesn't create directory nor any files:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = [ 'src/main/java' ]
        }
    }
    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = [ 'src/generated/java' ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't really want to do that. Hand written sources and generated sources should not be in the same directory. Instead add the place where the generated .java files are to the source locations.

Comment: Ok, but now generated .java files reside with compiled .class files in the same directory - shouldn't they be in a separate directory, e.g. "src/generated/java" ? If so, how can I move generated classes to a different directory and then add that to the source location in Gradle so they all get compiled? I've updated the question with the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This is the part you are missing:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << "-s"
    options.compilerArgs << "$projectDir/generated/java" 

    doFirst {
        // make sure that directory exists
        file(new File(projectDir, "/generated/java")).mkdirs()
    }   
}

clean.doLast {
    // clean-up directory when necessary
    file(new File(projectDir, "/generated")).deleteDir()
}
```